# Can Rails Routing Helpers (i.e. mymodel_path(model)) be Used in Models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing, helpermethods

Say I have a Rails Model called Thing. Thing has a url attribute that can **optionally** be set to a URL somewhere on the Internet. In view code, I need logic that does the following:

```
<% if thing.url.blank? %>
<%= link_to('Text', thing_path(thing)) %>
<% else %>
<%= link_to('Text', thing.url) %>
<% end %>
```

This conditional logic in the view is ugly. Of course, I could build a helper function, which would change the view to this:

```
<%= thing_link('Text', thing) %>
```

That solves the verbosity problem, but I would really prefer having the functionality in the model itself. In which case, the view code would be:

```
<%= link_to('Text', thing.link) %>
```

This, obviously, would require a link method on the model. Here's what it would need to contain:

```
def link
  (self.url.blank?) ? thing_path(self) : self.url
end
```

To the point of the question, thing_path() is an undefined method inside Model code. I'm assuming it's possible to "pull in" some helper methods into the model, but how? And is there a real reason that routing only operates at the controller and view layers of the app? I can think of lots of cases where model code may need to deal with URLs (integrating with external systems, etc).

Comment: A use case would be: to generate shortened url from goo.gl in an aftersave,

Comment: You should probably wrap you model in a presenter if you want to add view logic, this will keep the MVC layers separated. See Draper(https://github.com/jcasimir/draper).

Comment: See also the "URL generation for named routes" section in the documentation at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html

Answer (score 742):

In Rails 3 and higher:

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

e.g.

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.posts_path
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.posts_url(:host => "example.com")
```

Comment: Ypu can include this into any module and after it you can access url-helpers there. Thx

Comment: Save yourself from copying your `:host` option everywhere and set it once in your environment config files: `Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'localhost:3000'`

Comment: `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` worked for me on Rails 4

Comment: In Rails v3.2.18 I was able to add `self.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'www.example.com'` to my `config/application.rb` to have it available everywhere. Probably could move it into the the `config/environments/*.rb` files to customize it for each environment mode.

Comment: `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` works for me in Rails 4.1

Comment: If you just need the path you can use :only_path => true as an option without passing the host parameter.

Comment: this seems to be good option: http://hawkins.io/2012/03/generating_urls_whenever_and_wherever_you_want/

Comment: It looks like in Rails 4.2, you have define `default_url_options` locally in the model.  @RenarsSirotins link worked well for me and makes it DRY.

Comment: Works in Rails 5.1.5 for me.

Answer (score 190):

I've found the answer regarding how to do this myself. Inside the model code, just put:

For Rails <= 2:

```
include ActionController::UrlWriter
```

For Rails 3:

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

This magically makes `thing_path(self)` return the URL for the current thing, or `other_model_path(self.association_to_other_model)` return some other URL.

Comment: Just an update, since the above is deprecated. This is the current include:`include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`

Comment: I get NoMethodError (undefined method `optimize_routes_generation?' for #<ActionView::Base:0x007fe8c0eecbd0>) when I try this

Answer (score 134):

You may also find the following approach cleaner than including every method:

```
class Thing
  delegate :url_helpers, to: 'Rails.application.routes' 

  def url
    url_helpers.thing_path(self)
  end
end
```

Comment: Documentation on this seemed hard to find, so here is a decent link regarding the use of delegate in ActiveSupport. http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/12/inside-ruby-on-rails-delegate/

Comment: I get a `undefined local variable or method 'url_helpers' for Event:Class` error... :(

Comment: I get `undefined method url_helpers`. What I gonna do?

Comment: @asiniy, are You sure You've used delegate option to url_helpers that is written after class declaration?

Comment: Doesn't work, but it might be that this only works if you create your own `class`, as shown in the answer. If your Model class already extends `< ApplicationRecord` this won't work?

Answer (score 14):

Any logic having to do with what is displayed in the view should be delegated to a helper method, as methods in the model are strictly for handling data.

Here is what you could do:

```
# In the helper...

def link_to_thing(text, thing)
  (thing.url?) ? link_to(text, thing_path(thing)) : link_to(text, thing.url)
end

# In the view...

<%= link_to_thing("text", @thing) %>
```

Comment: What I don't like about helper methods in this case: When I look at link_to_thing(), I have to decide whether that's a thing-specific or application-wide helper (it easily could be either). I need to consider checking 2 files for the source. thing.link leaves no question about the source file.

Comment: Also, what if I need to use this functionality in a Rake task (to export a CSV file of thing URLs perhaps)... going directly to the model would be much better in that case as well.

Comment: But the difference is that the link_to wouldn't be available in the model, since it is an ActionView helper. So, this would not work. You could hack some attribute defaults in the model, so if it isn't set, it defaults to something, but that's up to you.

Comment: With web services APIs growing, often times models need to contact external resources with their own data and provide callback URLs. For example, a photo object needs to post itself to Socialmod, which will call back to that photo's URL when moderation is performed. An after_create() hook would make sense to post to Socialmod, but how do you know the callback URL? I think the author's own answer makes good sense.

Comment: Whilst you are right in strictly technical sense, there are times when people just need things to work without having to shave every yak there is to avoid violating some sacred design pattern or what have you, maybe they need to get the url, and actually store it in the database, would be handy then for a model to just know how to do that instead of passing things back and forth, sometimes rules can be broken.

Comment: If you need to break the rules for a simple model know his url... well,  something is really broken in your code.

Answer (score 10):

I really like following clean solution.

```
class Router
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  def self.default_url_options
    ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options
  end
end

router = Router.new
router.posts_url  # http://localhost:3000/posts
router.posts_path # /posts
```

It's from https://web.archive.org/web/20200221203515/https://www.hawkins.io/2012/03/generating_urls_whenever_and_wherever_you_want/

Comment: Link is broken FYI

Comment: Updated to link from archive.

Comment: Absolutely great, but is it possible to get hostname not from mailer but the way Rails itself does?

Answer (score 1):

While there might be a way I would tend to keep that kind of logic out of the Model. I agree that you shouldn't put that in the view ([keep it skinny](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/10/18/skinny-controller-fat-model)) but unless the model is returning a url as a piece of data to the controller, the routing stuff should be in the controller.

Comment: Re: "Unless the model is returning a URL as a piece of data". That's exactly what is happening here... the Model "owns" this piece of data, which is either a link to an on-site or off-site URL. In some cases the URL is generated from Rails Routing. In other cases, the URL is user-supplied data.

Answer (score 0):

*(Edit: Forget my previous babble...)*

Ok, there might be situations where you would go either to the model or to some other url... But I don't really think this belongs in the model, the view (or maybe the model) sounds more apropriate.

About the routes, as far as I know the routes is for the actions in controllers (wich usually "magically" uses a view), not directly to views. The controller should handle all requests, the view should present the results and the model should handle the data and serve it to the view or controller. I've heard a lot of people here talking about routes to models (to the point I'm allmost starting to beleave it), but as I understand it: routes goes to controllers. Of course a lot of controllers are controllers for one model and is often called `<modelname>sController` (e.g. "UsersController" is the controller of the model "User").

If you find yourself writing nasty amounts of logic in a view, try to move the logic somewhere more appropriate; request and internal communication logic probably belongs in the controller, data related logic may be placed in the model (but not display logic, which includes link tags etc.) and logic that is purely display related would be placed in a helper.

Comment: Say you have an Image model. If the Image has an associated outside URL with it, then point to that URL. Otherwise, point to the Image's show page to upload an image? Just an idea.

Comment: How about this less generic example:

link_to "Full Size Image", image.link

The link method in the model would either link to the on-site URL (image_path), or to, say, a Flickr URL if the user provided one and .url was set on the image.