# How to access routes in Resque worker class?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, resque

I am running on Rails 3.1 RC5. Resque doesn't seem like it is able to access root_url from a worker class. I tried putting `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` to no avail.

For example:

```
module EncodePhoto
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  def self.perform()
    puts root_url
  end
end
```

Returns:

```
undefined method `root_url' for EncodePhoto:Module
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am in a `rails console`, I can write:

```
include ActionController::UrlWriter
```

and then I can access the routes I need. Perhaps it can apply to your problem as well?

EDIT: Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011834/uninitialized-content-when-trying-to-include-actioncontrollerurlwriter-in-model). Here's the accepted answer from there:

```
include ActionDispatch::Routing::UrlFor
include ActionController::PolymorphicRoutes
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
default_url_options[:host] = 'example.com'
```

Comment: Perhaps it's not the case, but did you try to clear the browser's cache?