# How to use routing helpers in a model with Rails 3?

Tags: routes, model, ruby-on-rails-3

In a model callback I make an API call and need to give the API some URLs. Those URLs would be easily generated by a routing helper.

The solution given in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341143/can-rails-routing-helpers-i-e-mymodel-pathmodel-be-used-in-models)
does not work anymore in Rails 3.

Any solution? Thanks :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Got an answer from the rails IRC: just add

```
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

to your model

Comment: this may cause an infinite loop error.  If so you, can use delegate, i.e `delegate :url_helpers, to: 'Rails.application.routes'`

Answer (score 17):

In Rails 3 you can use:

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

e.g.

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.posts_path
```