# Rails, get resource path in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources

How do I get the path to a resource in the model? I need to store it in the database and would like the same url as you get from resourcename_path(resource)

Comment: For fullest answers, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/341143/793946

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In Rails 3, you can include the url helpers in models (though it normally is not the best way of dealing with things):

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
end
```

In Rails 2, I think it's `include ActionController::UrlWriter`, but I can't remember. Google is your friend.

Comment: Rails 2 is ActionView::Helpers:UrlHelper and ActionController::UrlWriter

Comment: Your Rails 3 solution generates the following error: RuntimeError: Missing host to link to! Please provide :host parameter or set default_url_options[:host]

Comment: @jvatic, If you use _url as opposed to _path, you need to tell it what the host is. In views it can take the current host, but models have no knowledge of that and so need to be told what to use.

Comment: If I have to specify the host I might as well just hard code the url, looks like I've found a way to get around needing it in the model anyways. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @jvatic: could you mind giving us the answer here?

Comment: @Sadiksha are you referring to the Rails 2 solution? The code above works in Rails 3... Basically you include the module containing the desired helper and define any variables it expects (found either by reading its code or undefined var/method exceptions).

Comment: Save yourself from copying your `:host` option everywhere and set it once in your environment config files: `Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'localhost:3000'`

Answer (score 86):

In Rails 3 and Rails 4 you can use:

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

e.g.

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.posts_path
```

Comment: One hour of searching and nobody managed to give me as simple and clear answer as yours. Thanks a lot.

Comment: FYI, if you need to access routes for engines, the equivalent is: MyEngineName::Engine.routes.url_helpers.some_path

Comment: Save yourself from copying your `:host` option everywhere and set it once in your environment config files: `Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'localhost:3000'`

Comment: `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.posts_path` did the job! Thanks!