# How to call routing helper inside a module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have a module like this, where "partners_url" is a routing helper method

```
module A
    def B
    ....partners_url
    end
end
```

but i get this

> NoMethodError - undefined method

How can i call that url helper in side a module?, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Put this line under your module declaration

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

Read about other options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074831/how-to-access-url-helper-from-rails-module)