# How to get url_for an object in Model method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, actionmailer

I would like to create a string that include a path for an object in Rails.

```
  def notification_content   
      "#{app.listing_url(my_listing, :host => "example.com")}. " +
  end
```

This content will then be fed into my ActionMailer as email content.

In console, it works fine. However, when I run it on localhost server, I get the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `app'
```

How should I go about it? Also, how can I make the path to be a hyperlink?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
def notification_content   
  "#{listing_url(my_listing, :host => "example.com")}. " + ...
end
```

Comment: details here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341143/can-rails-routing-helpers-i-e-mymodel-pathmodel-be-used-in-models

Comment: No need to include; you can just call on that object directly:

Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.url_for(...)

Comment: This will not work in Rails 5 for those visiting here in the future.

Answer (score 4):

(From the comments, credit to [Edward Anderson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87298/edward-anderson))

---

Prepend url_for with:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.*url_for(...)*
```