# rails url helper in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to access a url helper that I'm using in my `event` controller like this `event_url(event)`.

Is there a way to access this in my `event` model?

Something like this?

```
event_url(self)
```

Im using rails v2.3.11.

Comment: Note that @Farhan uses Rails 2.  
ActionController::UrlWriter is deprecated in Rails 3, see some usefull links on http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/UrlWriter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can Rails Routing Helpers (i.e. mymodel\_path(model)) be Used in Models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341143/can-rails-routing-helpers-i-e-mymodel-pathmodel-be-used-in-models)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding this in your model

```
include ActionController::UrlWriter
```

You also need to add config lines to env configs: 
development.rb

```
config.action_controller.default_url_options = {:host => "localhost:3000"}
```

production.rb

```
config.action_controller.default_url_options = {:host => "example.com"}
```

Comment: I tried this but it did not work. undefined method `event_url' for #<Event:0x111f502c8>

Comment: try to include this `ActionController::UrlWriter`

Comment: In Rails 3 it's possible to do it like this: `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.event_url`
I'm not sure if it works in Rails 2

Comment: Ok well something happened. I tried adding ActionController:UrlWriter and this is what I got back. Missing host to link to! Please provide :host parameter or set default_url_options[:host]

Comment: That's easy `event_url(self, :host => "localhost:3000")`

Comment: It's example just to try if it works =) 
Really you need to add config lines to env configs:
development.rb
`config.action_controller.default_url_options = {:host => "localhost:3000"}`
production.rb
`config.action_controller.default_url_options = {:host => "example.com"}`

Comment: @0A0D Ok. I'll remember that. 
AnatoliyKukul can you please update your answer with the correct answer from the comments.

Comment: I believe that should be `config.action_mailer.default_url_options` and NOT `config.action_controller.default_url_options`. Reference - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html