# Add rails route helpers to a class as class methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

How can i add rails route helpers like "root_path" to a class like my_model.rb as a **class method**?

So my class is like this:

```
Class MyModel

  def self.foo
    return self.root_path
  end

end

MyModel.foo
```

The above doesn't work because Class MyModel doesn't respond to root_path

This is what I know:

1. I can use include `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`, but that only add the module's methods as instance methods
2. I tried doing extend `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` but it **didn't work**

Please feel free to school me :)

Comment: This is the wrong approach with MVC. You should add route related methods at the app's controller or helper level.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341143/can-rails-routing-helpers-i-e-mymodel-pathmodel-be-used-in-models

Comment: how is it a duplicate. they are adding it as instance methods. i want to add it as class methods. and thats my questions: how to add the modules instance methods as class methods

Answer (score 17, accepted):

URL routes shouldn't generally need to be accessed from a model. Typically you should only need to access them from your controller when handling a request, or when rendering a view (if you're e.g. formatting a link URL).

So instead of asking your model object for the root path, you would simply call `root_path` from within your controller or a view.

**Edit**

If you're just interested in the reason why you're unable to include the module's method as class methods in your class, I would not expect a simple `include` to work, since that would include the module's methods as as *instance* methods in your class.

`extend` would normally work, but in this case it does not due to how the `url_helpers` method is implemented. From [actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb#L350) source

```
def url_helpers
  @url_helpers ||= begin
    routes = self

    helpers = Module.new do
...
      included do
        routes.install_helpers(self)
        singleton_class.send(:redefine_method, :_routes) { routes }
      end
```

The `included` block containing the `routes.install_helpers(self)` call indicates that you will need to `include` the module in order to get the methods install (so `extend` is out).

The following should work if you call `extend` in the class context. Try this:

```
Class MyModel
  class << self
    include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  end
end
Class.root_path
```

Comment: well i understand your point but thats not my question. I am asking how to add instance methods of a module as class methods. I know doing extend should work, but its not working in the case i mentioned. Do you know why?

Comment: @user566245 Gotcha. I've updated my answer, please take another look

Comment: @user566245 Did this work for you? Please give it a try and upvote/accept the answer if it worked out, thanks!