# Figuring out rails routes, getting undefined method for my detail_path

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes

My data of a datatable:

```
def data
    theusers.map do |usermap|
      [
        h(usersmap.spriden_last_name),
        h(usermap.spriden_first_name),
        h(usermap.spriden_id),
        link_to(usermap.gobtpac_username, detail_path(usermap.spriden_id))
      ]
    end
end
```

the above code resides in `app\datatables\helpdesk_datatable.rb`

The above works mostly I know it is getting the data, the error I get is with the detail_path

`Error on "undefined method" for detail_path...` This means it is not building the router dynamically right, correct?

Or I am passing in the wrong thing I tried to pass in usermap.spriden.id and just banner user, same issue.  I am really not sure how routes work apparently.  I have a details_controller.rb in controllers that has a show method in it and i have the views/details/show.html.erb  which will show the data that was passed into the route, at least I thought.  But is it just an ID or an object? so if it just an id i have to look it up again in 
the show method right?  How do routes like this look? I am using devise and cancan too here is my routes file:

```
NmsuMyaccount::Application.routes.draw do
 authenticated :user do
   root :to => 'home#index'
   match 'home', :to => 'home#index', :via => :get 
 end


 #get 'show-details' => "details#show", as: 'show_details'

 resources :details
 devise_for :users
 resources :users
 # In order for an unauthorized user access this controller#action, this needs to be in  a scope, but I don't know why.
 devise_scope :user do
   match 'home', :to => 'home#index', :via => :get
 end

end
```

Also hitting the end point localhost:3000 is an error, I have to goto /home, although devise does work just fine.  So thought I was close but for the life of me cannot get the detail_path to work, and I thought it was a plural issue so tried details, and just detail no path etc.  No dice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that you have access to the route helpers that Rails provides inside your custom class. So you have to manually include the module inside your class. Something like:

```
link_to(usermap.gobtpac_username, Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.detail_path(usermap.spriden_id))
```

Or:

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
# Use it like you are using.
```

See here for more information about the subject:
[Can Rails Routing Helpers (i.e. mymodel_path(model)) be Used in Models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341143/can-rails-routing-helpers-i-e-mymodel-pathmodel-be-used-in-models)

Comment: Man that was it, good to know I wasn't totally off my rocker and missed this.  Thanks!  Scoping sometimes trips me up in this rails framework.  I did try your second way of using the include, it gave me a “SystemStackError: stack level too deep” error so tried the previous suggestion, worked like a charm.  I am guessing including the whole Rails.application.routes.url_helpers made for some sort of recursion to happen.