# Access to rails engine route helpers outside views/controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I couldn't find this anywhere and just went in circles with it so I figured someone else might benefit. How do you get access to rails url helpers in an engine?

For the core app, I can do something like this:

```
class Thingy < ActiveRecord::Base    
 include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
 ...
end
```

But this doesnt work in models in an engine.

Comment: Apparently I can't answer my own question yet as a SO noob so here's the answer in a comment for now:

Looks like you need to specify the routes that're particular to your engine. So in your engine's model, for example, you can do this:

    module Blog
     class Stuffy
      include Blog::Engine.routes.url_helpers
      ...
     end
    end

And now you can use the url helpers from your engine inside your engine's models.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Rails Routing Helpers (i.e. mymodel\_path(model)) be Used in Models?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341143/can-rails-routing-helpers-i-e-mymodel-pathmodel-be-used-in-models)

Answer (score 12):

Looks like you need to specify the routes that're particular to your engine. So in your engine's model, for example, you can do this:

```
module Blog
 class Stuffy
  include Blog::Engine.routes.url_helpers
  ...
 end
end
```

And now you can use the url helpers from your engine inside your engine's models.

Comment: As your mentioned in your question- someone else might benefit - looks like I did. Thanks a lot for this one!!! Spent half a day looking for a work around.