# How can I find a resource path in a model when using an engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, spree, rails-routing

While using Spree, a Rails ecommerce engine, I was trying to save the products_path in my Spree::Product model for tracking.

[Looking on SO I found this solution, which looked like the perfect answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341143/can-rails-routing-helpers-i-e-mymodel-pathmodel-be-used-in-models/5456103#5456103)

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.products_path
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.products_url(:host => "example.com")
```

But using that solution just gave me the following error.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `products_path' for #<Module:0x007fe9e208e908>
```

Much frustration....

Comment: Shouldnt it be `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.products_path`? Is it a typo?

Comment: @AmitBadhekaPykihStaff I don't understand what you mean.  What you have typed is identical to what is in the question.  Are you asking why doesn't that work?

Answer (score 2):

When using an Rails Engine, you need to use the Engine's route helpers rather than the main Rails application route helpers.

```
Spree::Core::Engine.routes.url_helpers.products_path
Spree::Core::Engine.routes.url_helpers.products_url(:host => "example.com")
```

**Bonus tip:**

If you want to get rid of the `:host => "example.com"` paramater, you can add a host designator in your environment configuration file.

Just like for the url_helpers, for an engine, you will need to add the default under the Engine routes.

```
# in config -> environments -> development.rb

Spree::Core::Engine.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'localhost:3000'
```

Note: *this **does not** set a default host for Rails.application.routes.url_helpers* ;-)

Comment: I'd like to give credit to @theo-scholiadis for leading me down the right path.  Thanks!!