# Rails - return html black from model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a method in my model which is called in a modal like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-9"><%= @notification.notifier_context %></div>
```

In this method, I want to return some HTML like this, which has a rails helper path in it.

```
context = "<td><%= link_to('link', account_item_path(@item.account, @item))%></td>".html_safe
```

But its just out-putting the string as is.  How can I get it evaluated to HTML proper?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
"<td>#{link_to('link', Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.account_item_path(@item.account, @item))}</td>".html_safe
```

String is not erb template so you can't use <%= %> syntax.
Also it's great idea to use helpers (with [content_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag)) or [partials](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) for that. 
Also if you need to use routes inside model class, read [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341143/can-rails-routing-helpers-i-e-mymodel-pathmodel-be-used-in-models).

Comment: This answer works great - hopefully it is a suitable way of achieving this!

Comment: @user3437721 The best way will be to use separate partial for that. In general model is not used for displaying views.

Comment: it is a _form.html.erb partial currently, which calls a method in the model

Comment: so you can create another partial, pass a @notification there as local variable and render what you want (see doc about partials for examples).

Comment: Yes, now it will work.. First answer was wrong. But this is not a best approach.