# Rails.application.routes.url_helpers missing method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've read here [Can Rails Routing Helpers (i.e. mymodel_path(model)) be Used in Models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341143/can-rails-routing-helpers-i-e-mymodel-pathmodel-be-used-in-models) how to include the url helpers in my model. However, when I try to run `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.products_path` from within my models, I get a `NoMethodError: undefined method products_path for #<Module:0x007fea1d4ffa38>`.

The same thing happens, when I try it within a view:

```
<%= products_path %> # generates /products
<%= Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.products_path %> # raises a NoMethodError
```

Any idea, why this is happening? I'm on Rails 3.2.9

**Update**:

This is my `routes.rb` (the important parts):

```
Spree::Core::Engine.routes.draw do
  resources :products
end

MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  class IsCityConstraint
    def matches?(request)
      Spree::CityZone.where(:url => request.params[:city_name]).exists?
    end
  end
  mount Spree::Core::Engine, :at => ':city_name/', :constraints => IsCityConstraint.new, :as => :city
  mount Spree::Core::Engine, :at => '/'
end
```

So, I have an existing engine, where I add more routes, and this engine gets mounted to `/` and to `/:city_name`.

**Update:**

Here is part of the output of `rake routes`:

```
                           products GET      /products(.:format)                                                      spree/products#index
                                    POST     /products(.:format)                                                      spree/products#create
                        new_product GET      /products/new(.:format)                                                  spree/products#new
                       edit_product GET      /products/:id/edit(.:format)                                             spree/products#edit
                            product GET      /products/:id(.:format)                                                  spree/products#show
                                    PUT      /products/:id(.:format)                                                  spree/products#update
                                    DELETE   /products/:id(.:format)                                                  spree/products#destroy
```

Comment: Could you provide more details about an error that raises?

Comment: It just raises the `NoMethodError`, nothing more

Comment: How did you set the route for this? Could you show the `routes.rb`?

Comment: I've updated my question

Comment: I don't use Spree, according your code you should do something like this: Spree::Core::Engine.routes.url_helpers.products_path

Comment: What does `rake routes` show?

Comment: Ah, thank you `Spree::Core::Engine.routes.url_helpers` was the solution! Add it as an answer, so I can accept it ;)

Comment: May I ask why you're looking to access routes in the model?

Comment: I have a method in my product model, that converts it to google shopping format. And here you need the field `link` that points to that product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `products_path` inside `Spree` routes. You can use this:

```
Spree::Core::Engine.routes.url_helpers.products_path
```

Comment: This is kinda the long way. A better one would be to directly call the `spree` routes engine: `spree.products_path`. If you ever define a `products_path` in you main application, you can call it via `main_app.products_path`.