# Can't use url_helpers link_to in initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, initializer

So I am extending `String` in an initializer that requires a `model_path` function to be used:

```
class String
  def foo(bar)
    ...
    link_to(baz, baz_path(baz))
  end
end
```

So to get it to work I add

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

Problem is now I can't even view the website because there are weird problems with using `url_for` elsewhere:

```
wrong number of arguments (3 for 0..1)

  </script>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
--<%= mathjax_tag %>------- this line is highlighted as the problem --
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
```

If I remove that include, my application views get rendered successfully again. But remove that include, and my extension to the String class does not work anymore.

How can I keep the functionality of my function (I'm ok with moving it elsewhere if need be, so long as it's accessible to all of my models) and also keep the views rendered?

Comment: Does it have to be in the `String`? Seems like a bad idea to me. Try placing it in a separate class. `UrlUtil.foo(bar)`

Comment: Another idea: how about not mixing the url_helpers in? Use it directly: `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.user_path`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Rails Routing Helpers (i.e. mymodel\_path(model)) be Used in Models?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341143/can-rails-routing-helpers-i-e-mymodel-pathmodel-be-used-in-models)

Comment: @LannyBose that's where I got `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` from

Comment: @SergioTulentsev not mixing it in works great, thanks! Do you want to submit it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Including url_helpers into `String` just to use `something_path` method is shooting sparrows with a cannon. Rails is already a big mess of monkeypatching, no need to add more (you're almost guaranteed to break something).

Be less impactful and use url helpers without mixing them in:

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.user_path
```

I would also advise not to extend `String` at all. An excusable exception would be if you wanted to add new string-related functionality (something like `upcase` if it didn't exist). It seems to be not the case, so don't do it.

Comment: Where would you recommend I put this helper function then?

Comment: As suggested in comments above, a separate util class/module

Answer (score -2):

To add on the previous answer you can use `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` on matching URLS just add in routes `:as` like the following example:

```
get "sessions/destroy/:param_id", as: :logout
```

so you can use it as following:

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.logout_path(:param_id => your_value)
```

This will do the same as url_for

Hopefully, this would help