# Rails: How can I use post_path in posts_helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a posts view that contains links to the adjacent posts. I've added a class in posts_helper to decide what the links should be.

show.html.erb:

```
<ul>
  <% links = PostsHelper::Links.new(@post) %>
  <li><%= links.older %></li>
  <li><%= links.newer %></li>
  <li><%= link_to 'show all', posts_path %></li>
</ul>
```

posts_helper.rb:

```
module PostsHelper
  class Links
    def initialize(post)
      @post = post
    end

    def newer
      link_to 'newer', post_path(newer_post)
    end

    def older
      link_to 'older', post_path(older_post)
    end

    private

    attr_reader :post

    def newer_post
      Post.where(['id > ?', post.id]).last
    end

    def older_post
      Post.where(['id < ?', post.id]).first
    end
  end
end
```

Routes:

```
Prefix Verb URI Pattern          Controller#Action
 posts GET  /posts(.:format)     posts#index
  post GET  /posts/:id(.:format) posts#show
```

But I can't access `post_path` within the helper class. I get an error:

```
undefined method `post_path' for #<PostsHelper::Links:0x007fb884ad10d0>
```

This makes me think that I'm not going about things the 'rails' way.

How do I go about using the `posts_path` helper? Or have I veered too far from the ideal method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're closer than you think! But, it looks to me like you're heading toward the `Presenter` pattern - not the `Helper` pattern. Check out [RailsCast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHsq6aFlP0U) for a better discussion.

So, let's say you have something like:

```
app/presenters/posts/show_presenter.rb

class Posts::ShowPresenter

    def initialize(controller)
      @controller = controller
    end

    def newer_link
      link_to 'newer', post_path(newer_post)
    end

    def older_link
      link_to 'older', post_path(older_post)
    end

  private

    def controller()          @controller                             end
    def params()              controller.params                       end
    def view_context()        controller.view_context                 end

    def newer_post
      Post.where(['id > ?', post.id]).last
    end

    def older_post
      Post.where(['id < ?', post.id]).first
    end    

    def post
      get_controller_variable(:post)
    end

    def get_controller_variable(sym)
      controller.instance_variable_get("@#{sym}")
    end

    def method_missing(*args, &block)
      view_context.send(*args, &block)
    end

end
```

Now, let's say in your PostsController, you do something like:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @post = Post.find_some_clever_way
    @presenter = Posts::ShowPresenter.new(self)
    ...
  end

end
```

In your partial, you should now be able to do something like:

```
<ul>
  <li><%= @presenter.older_link %></li>
  <li><%= @presenter.newer %></li>
  <li><%= link_to 'show all', posts_path %></li>
</ul>
```

Most of the magic lies in that `method_missing` definition. It basically allows your presenter to use the `view_context` from the controller to do things like render `link_to` and generate `post_path`.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the path to your helpers:

```
# View
PostsHelper::Links.new(@post, posts_path)

# Helper
module PostsHelper
  class Links
    def initialize(post, path)
      @post = post
      @path = path
    end
```

Alternatively, as [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5456103/52317) states, you can access route helpers like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.posts_path
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.posts_url(:host => "example.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to include `ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper` for view helper `link_to` to be available in your custom helper and `Rails.application.routes` for path generation.

try this:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper

module PostsHelper
  class Links
    delegate :url_helpers, to: 'Rails.application.routes'

    def initialize(post)
      @post = post
    end

    def newer
      link_to 'newer', url_helpers.post_path(newer_post)
    end

    def older
      link_to 'older', url_helpers.post_path(older_post)
    end

    private

    attr_reader :post

    def newer_post
      Post.where(['id > ?', post.id]).last
    end

    def older_post
      Post.where(['id < ?', post.id]).first
    end
  end
end
```